# Docker container doesn't exit after completing program

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, container-image

I'm trying to run Java container as one time job in Kubernetes. The base image which I'm using is `gcr.io/distroless/java`. The problem is sometimes the container keeps running forever after the program completes.

Here is Kubernetes Job configuration:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: false
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: gcr.io/my_company/image:test
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 3Gi
          requests:
            memory: 1Gi
      restartPolicy: Never
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
  backoffLimit: 0
```

Here is the sample of my Java code:

```
package com.mypackage.prod;

import *some packages*;

public class Main {
    /*Static resources*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.info("Starting");

        /*
        Doing some work and calling couple of functions!
        */

        LOG.info("Done with my work. Hitting System exit");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I've also tried using `gcr.io/distroless/java:debug` and checked the logs via docker `attach`. After the program completes, I see the last log statement but the Pod & Job still exists. Pod remains in active status while Job in running status.

Running on Google Kubernetes Engine with Master version: `1.12.7-gke.10`

I've to then manually clean such jobs and pods using `kubectl delete jobs $job-name --grace-period=0 --force`

Comment: Ignoring Kubernetes, a Java program won't `System.exit` if there's any non-daemon threads still running. So check if your program is starting any threads, particularly in any libraries you are using.

Comment: @Hitobat I tried adding `Runtime.getRuntime().halt(0)` still no effect :-/

Comment: Is there a sidecar (for example you have Istio installed)? I heard an issue where a sidecar doesn't terminate when a job does.

Comment: @ChanseokOh there is no sidecar, just our java container.

Comment: Can you paste your Dockerfile?